# PHP - Remove 2 parts of a string

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure this out as I've never needed to do this before, but how would I remove 2 parts of the string? This is what I have so far..

```
str_replace('/pm ', '', $usrmsg)
```

$usrmsg would be what the user sent in my chat room, I've already removed /pm but this needs 2 variables...

1: The username
2: The message to the user

Usernames don't have spaces, therefore after the 2nd word, the message to the user will be inputted. How can I remove the first 2 parts of the string separately?

Comment: You could enclose the username using special chars such as <Username>

Comment: Please give us an example of input.

Comment: Buddy - Users could send a message like this

/pm matt Hey Matt, here's my message to you...

Comment: I really cant understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '/pm username bla bla bla';

list($comand, $user, $text) = explode(" ", $string, 3);

// $comand  --> /pm
// $user    --> username
// $text    --> bla bla bla
```

or simply

```
list(, $user, $text) = explode(" ", $string, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions. Should be something like this:

```
if(preg_match('#^/pm ([A-Za-z]+) (.*)$#',$message,$matches))
     var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: As with the below answer, I didn't think to try something like this, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you've removed the `/pm`, and you just need the next word?

```
// remove the /pm
$usrmsg = str_split('/pm', '', $usrmsg);

// split the usrmsg by space
$parts = str_split(' ', $usrmsg);

// the username is the first part
$username = $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with regular expressions, use something like this:

```
$inp = '/pm matt Hey Matt, here\'s my message to you...';

preg_match('~^\/pm\s?(?P<username>.*?)\s(?P<message>.*?)$~', $inp, $matches);

echo $matches['username'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $matches['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the explode() method as follows

```
$tokens = explode(' ', "/pm matt hi matt this is maatt too", 3);
print_r($tokens);
```

The first element of array will have "/pm", the second username and the third will have the message.